# How can I list disk usage of network shares on a Windows server?

Tags: disk-space, windows-server

I'm looking for a way to show me the disk usage of all the network shares on my Windows Server.

Does such a method exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about showing just the network shares, but [TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) from JAM Software will display the disk usage of folders.

Beow is a screen shot of the application which shows how it displays the size of folders both as a value (e.g. 3.7GB) and as a yellow bar graph.

[image: Screenshot of TreeSize]

You could you that as a starting point...

Comment: Could you perhaps add a figure that shows what it does?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Done.